# Handle only else condition in swift 'if let' using 'where'

Tags: ios, swift, option-type

I have a logic condition:

```
if let login = login where validateLogin(login) {
    // I'm not interested in this condition
} else {
    // This is interesting
}
```

Is there any option to write somehow if let condition to not handle true condition (because I dont want to do anything with that)? So, something like negation:

```
!(if let login = login where validateLogin(login)) {
    // This is interesting
}
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Unless I am missing something here, should you try:
`if let login != login where validateLogin(login)`. Notice the `!` before the `=`. Let me know if that does it.

Comment: It gives an error with if let login != login.

Comment: No, if let aValue = anOptional is a pattern matching statement, not a comparison. If anOptional contains a value, it binds the value to a name and enters the block.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first branch in your if condition is actual made up of 2 criteria:

- `if let` is a check for non-null
- `where` is a syntactic sugar for a follow up condition, when you can be sure that the variable is not null.

You can reverse the logic like this:

```
if login == nil || !validateLogin(login!) {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 7):

In Swift 1.2 something like this is not possible but you can use:

```
// since where is logically the same as &&
if !(login != nil && validateLogin(login!)) {
    // This is interesting
}

// or
if login == nil || !validateLogin(login!) {
    // This is interesting
}
```

which is logically the same as your desired implementation. Note: because both the `&&` and the `||` operator wrap the right side of the expression in a closure the force unwrap is even "safe".

Looking forward to Swift 2 we get a new `guard` statement which handles the else part first:

```
guard let login = login where validateLogin(login) else {
    // This is interesting
}

// use the unwrapped login here if you want
```

Comment: Also to note: with the guard statement you have to have a `return`, `break`, `continue` or a `@noreturn` function within the else body